# How to generate a graphic on the fly with cherrypy

Tags: python, dynamic, graph, cherrypy

I am developing a small web application using cherrypy and I would like to generate some graphs from the data stored in a database.  The web pages with tables are easy and I plan to use matplotlib for the graphs themselves, but how do I set the content-type for the method so they return images instead of plain text?   Will cherrypy "sniff" the result and change the content-type automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the content-type header of the response manually, either in the app config, using the `response.headers` tool, or in the handler method.

In the handler method, there are two options covered on the [MimeDecorator](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/MimeDecorator) page of the Cherrypy Tools wiki.

In the method body:

```
def hello(self):
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type']= 'image/png'
    return generate_image_data()
```

Or using the tool decorator in Cherrypy 3:

```
@cherrypy.tools.response_headers([('Content-Type', 'image/png')])
def hello(self):
    return generate_image_data()
```

The wiki also defines a custom decorator:

```
def mimetype(type):
    def decorate(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = type
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorate

class MyClass:        
    @mimetype("image/png")
    def hello(self):
        return generate_image_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the content type of the response:

```
cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
```